# Ruby on Rails Image Upload/Text Overlay

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, imagemagick

I'm new to using ruby on rails and was looking for help with image upload/manipulation.  The extend of my RoR experience is the rails tutorial blog project, but I've used Java and PHP for numerous other projects.  I'm trying to create a simple app where the user uploads a file, enters some text, and the text is overlayed on the supplied image (similar to icanhascheezburger.com).  I'm planning on using imagemagick to add the text, but am having difficultly uploading the image.  Any suggestions or example code?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggested using Paperclip, https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip for your file upload.  Also, for the image editing, checkout RMagick, http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/, a Ruby interface between Ruby and Imagemagick.

This blog post has a basic tutorial that might be helpful as well. http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/adding-text-to-pictures-with-rmagick-and-rails/